# Fencing Tactic for Pulling an Opponent's Blade Out of Line

Tags: tactics, fencing

I fenced in high school years ago and our coach talked of a tactic to pull an opponents' blade out of line, gradually.  If I recall correctly, it was done with small attacks, each a bit further out, drawing the parry a bit further with each attack.

Often, the defender would execute the parry but come back slightly off-line to a point where a small feint would allow for an easy score.

Is this really a thing?  It has been a VERY long time.  I've been trying to remember the term (if it does exist.) Any help out there?